# javascript stale closure problem when pass object

Tags: javascript, closures

```
// Example 0, revisited - this is BUGGY!
    function useState(initialValue) {
      var _val = initialValue
      // no state() function
      function setState(newVal) {
        _val = newVal
      }
      return [_val, setState] // directly exposing _val
    }
    var [foo, setFoo] = useState({x: 1})
    console.log(foo) // {x: 1}
    setFoo({x: 2}) // sets _val inside useState's scope
    console.log(foo) // {x: 1}
```

I understand a pass-by-value or pass-by-reference problem. But below example still confused me? Can you tell me which step I am wrong. That is: We pass by an object to `_val`, but it's not change the reference value outside.

Is this means the `_val` in closure is different from outside? Although they looks same. So when we assign an object to it, it refer to a new memory, and this memory is shared by all closures in one function. Because another example below is correct.

```js
function useState(initialValue) {
  var _val = initialValue
  // no state() function
  function setState(newVal) {
    _val = newVal
  }
  function getState() {
    return _val
  }
  return [getState, setState]
}
var [getState, setFoo] = useState({x: 1})
console.log(getState()) // {x: 1}
setFoo({x: 2}) 
console.log(getState()) // {x: 2}
```

Comment: "It's not a pass-by-value or pass-by-reference problem." — It really is

Comment: "Below example we pass by a reference." — No, you don't. You can't have a reference to a variable.

Comment: "*Does this mean all the closures in same function share the same memory?*" - [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi As the closure memory model, I thought the outside and closures share the same reference `_val`, but it's not? So the closures create another reference? just have the same name?

Comment: What do you mean by "outside"? Notice that `_val` is not a reference, it's a variable - which is referred to by all closures that have it in their scope

Comment: `Outside` means function the closure belongs. `_val` is used by function and closures inside, why we assign an object, we cannot change it? @Bergi

Comment: This has nothing to do with objects. Variables (and closures over them) work the same regardless whether they hold an object or a primitive value. "Changing an object" means mutating its properties, e.g. `_val.x = 2` or `foo.x = 2`, but that's not what you are doing. `foo` and `_val` are completely separate variables, even if they currently hold the same value, it doesn't mean that setting one variable to a different value affects the other.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, you are exactly right.